# How to run custom shell script just before EC2 stop/terminate using systemD services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, systemd

I want to run a shell script just before EC2 terminates or stops, i am using Amazon2 AMI. There is no support for Traditional SysVinit in Amazon2 Image, it relies on Daemon services . So i want to make use of systemD services.
My shell script will just gracefully shutdown the tomcat and make some DB changes, should not get executed for more than 2m.
Please suggest.

P.S - I do not want to use LifeCycle Hooks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately by the time you have stopped/terminated the EC2 instance it has entered a shutting down state which would stop this script from running.

If you're hesitant to trigger a script via lifecycle hooks then you will need to script this action.

- Look at using [Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) programatically.
- Add to the script the terminate or shutdown logic.

Comment: Thank you Chris for your reply, So is there anyway i can run script just before EC2 shutdown? Again was curious if we can just play around systemD services rather than using lifecycle hooks and AWS Systems Manager Run Command. But yeah in the end i have to use LifeCycle Hooks.

Comment: As per my answer you would need to script it, so have your script run the commands and then shutdown/terminate. By the time the AWS API has started shutting down or terminating it is too late to run commands :(